# can i use c4droid under bluestack to develop android games using c++?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, android-emulator, bluestacks

Since few days i started developing android apps after 5 years of c/c++ coding , i know the need to learn java for android and i have no problem with it , but i prefer to continue using **`c/c++`** , after long web search i found that the simplest way is by using c4droid ,since i don't currently have a android device , i think that my best solution is to run c4droid under blue stacks emulator and that way i will have no need to setup the `NDK` or "c++ builder" , now i have a little doubt , if that way is useful for serious game programming !! i know that **`c4droid`** support `sdl` and `opengl` and theoretically i can append any library in it , but can it reach such degree of confidence especially under **blue stack emulator** ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Android SDK is preferable over a simple app, however no one says that you cannot use it under Bluestacks.  The results depend on you.

EDIT:
If you find it comfortable and you get the same results you'd get with the "official"  way, why not do it your way?

Comment: thanks a lot , i am currently using android studio linked to Bluestacks emulator ,and there is no problem with it yet , i faced some problems with the c4droid under Bluestacks when i compile , a messages appears indicates that compiling succeed but when i run he console emulator is blank besides i installed the sdl and gcc plugin but in the c4droid menu i can't access their configuration and "the install sdl/gcc" options are bouth still enabled , like i didnt install it !!! i hope i could use it because it is sooo simple and it supports sdl that i am familiar with :/